# simple string concat manipulation in java

Tags: java, string

I want to get the following output:

> Hello Steve Andrews!

These are my variables:

```
a = "steve";
b = "Andrew"
```

I tried this:

```
System.out.print("Hello " + a + " " + b + "s");
```

I don't know where to put `.toUpper()` for `steve`. The `s` should be in uppercase. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I tried to do it without stringutils.. But anyways, thanks to all who helped :)

```
public class Hello
    {
      public static void main(String[] args){
        String a = "steve";
        String b = "Andrew";
        String firstletter = a.substring(0,1);
        String remainder = a.substring(1);
        String capitalized = firstletter.toUpperCase() + remainder.toLowerCase();

        System.out.print("Hello " + capitalized + " " + b + "s" );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [`StringUtils.capitalize(a)`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#capitalize%28java.lang.String%29),

```
"Hello " + StringUtils.capitalize(a) + " " + b + "s"
```

> Capitalizes a String changing the first letter to title case as per Character.toTitleCase(char). No other letters are changed.

Comment: hey what will I import when using stringutils?

Comment: You need to add the [commons-lang.jar](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven/commons-lang/jars/commons-lang-2.3.jar) in your classpath and `import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils`

Comment: It is now include in Java : //  (version 1.7 : 51.0, super bit)
public class com.sun.xml.internal.ws.util.StringUtils {

Comment: Don't ever use packages starting with com.sun.* or sun.*. They're internal and are no longer available in Java 9.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [StringUtils.capitalize(str)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#capitalize%28java.lang.String%29), or if you want to do it by yourself:

```
public static String capitalize(String str) {
    int strLen;
    if (str == null || (strLen = str.length()) == 0) {
        return str;
    }
    return new StringBuffer(strLen)
        .append(Character.toTitleCase(str.charAt(0)))
        .append(str.substring(1))
        .toString();
}
```

Comment: For a utility method, I'd recommend `StringBuilder` avoiding unnecessary synchronization overhead.

Comment: +1 for using Character, if you are not in Java 7, otherwise use StringUtils like Jigar Joshi show.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using this method:

```
public static String capitalize(String str) {
    str = (char) (str.charAt(0) - 32) + str.substring(1);
    return str;
}
```

Though it should be noted that this method assumes that the first character in str is indeed a lowercase letter.

Comment: ... and not just any lowercase letter. It basically works only in the ASCII range. Given the existence of `Charecter.toUpperCase` this approach is rather misguided.

Comment: I just figured that since it's such a simple case, this method should be sufficient and gives a little insight as to how a built-in method such as Character.toUpperCase might work at a lower level.

Comment: Perhaps... (btw downvote not mine) although it would be much more instructive if we were in the year 1992 :) Today it's more harm than good. `Character.toUpperCase` doesn't do any such simple thing; it consults some internal lookup tables---it's a general mechanism that works the same way for all Unicode.